# Optimize revolution slider on magento home page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, html

I have revolution slider on home page and need to optimize because on loading all the images are coming in request, So need to minimize the image request,

Any one have idea how can I hide this request during page load.

Comment: you can use lazyload functionality for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got Solution from below link :

http://previous.themepunch.com/revolution4-jquery/liveguide/10.Sample-LazyLoading.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery lazyload functionality you can use for load images on scroll instead of page load.

https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

If you will not get proper idea how to develop it, then I'll guide you.

Comment: lazyLoad:"on"  control is working for me

Comment: ok , Happy to help.